# run TestDB program with Apache Derby - java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null

Tags: java, sql, exception, derby

I tried to run test program to be prove that installation of Apache Derby was ok.
Installed accorded this tutorial [Install Apache Derby on Ubuntu](http://angshukutu.wordpress.com/2012/09/01/install-apache-derby-on-ubuntu/)

For run program have to type from terminal:

```
java -classpath driver_class_path:. TestDB database.properties
```

Code from `TestDB class:`

```
public class TestDB 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {   
      if (args.length == 0)
      {   
         System.out.println(
               "Usage: java -classpath driver_class_path" 
               + File.pathSeparator 
               + ". TestDB database.properties");
         return;
      }
      else 
         SimpleDataSource.init(args[0]);

      Connection conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection();
      try
      {
         Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

         stat.execute("CREATE TABLE Test (Name CHAR(20))");
         stat.execute("INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('Romeo')");

         ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Test");
         result.next();
         System.out.println(result.getString("Name"));

         stat.execute("DROP TABLE Test");
      }
      finally
      {
         conn.close();
      }
   }
}
```

from `SimpleDataSource class:`

```
public class SimpleDataSource
{
   private static String url;
   private static String username;
   private static String password;

   /**
      Initializes the data source.
      @param fileName the name of the property file that 
      contains the database driver, URL, username, and password
   */
   public static void init(String fileName)
         throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
   {  
      Properties props = new Properties();
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
      props.load(in);

      String driver = props.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
      url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
      username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
      if (username == null) username = "";
      password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");
      if (password == null) password = "";
      if (driver != null)
         Class.forName(driver);
   }

   /**
      Gets a connection to the database.
      @return the database connection
   */
   public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
   {
      return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
   }
}
```

content of `database.properties:`

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@larry.mathcs.sjsu.edu:1521:InvoiceDB
/usr/share/javadb
```

For ***database user name***  and ***database password*** blank lines.

And output after running:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~/Desktop/Big JAVA/bj4_code/ch22/test$ java -classpath /usr/share/javadb:. TestDB database.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:556)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at SimpleDataSource.getConnection(SimpleDataSource.java:45)
    at TestDB.main(TestDB.java:26)
```

***Update:***

I tried to use the derby embedded driver. I changed `database.properties` to

```
jdbc.driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:derby:InvoiceDB;create=true;
user=me;
password=mine
```

But after running I had next output:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~/Desktop/Big JAVA/bj4_code/ch22/test$ java -classpath /usr/share/javadb:. TestDB database.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at SimpleDataSource.init(SimpleDataSource.java:36)
    at TestDB.main(TestDB.java:24)
```

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@larry.mathcs.sjsu.edu:1521:InvoiceDB` is not a valid connection URL for Derby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A property file is of the form

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

You forgot the keys so all your `props.getProperty()` calls will return null.

Second, your database URL doesn't match to a derby database. It looks more like an Oracle database. And what driver class you use?

Maybe this would work

```
jdbc.driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/InvoiceDB;create=true;user=me;password=mine
```

Be sure you have started the Derby server beforehand.

If you want to use the embedded driver, the driver class is `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver` and the URL would be `jdbc:derby:InvoiceDB;create=true;user=me;password=mine`.

Comment: I updated question after trying to run. What about change this test to using mysql DB at Apache server. Which driver I should use? With MyPHPAdmin.

Comment: You need to include the `derby.jar` into your classpath. Take a look here: http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html#derby_configure

Comment: Of course you can switch to MySQL. Then you need the appropriate driver JAR, include it in your classpath and change the driver class. With MyPHPAdmin you can manage your MySQL databases but this is not related to access the database from Java. (You can use a tool like [Squirrel](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) to manage all kind of different databases.)

Comment: I added to my `.bashrc` - `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/javadb/bin/` and `export DERBY_HOME=/usr/share/javadb` during installation apache derby.

Comment: Ok, but this has nothing to do with your Java classpath. On top of your question in your command to run your application include the path to your `derby.jar` (replace your placeholder `driver_class_path` with the real path).

Comment: Hm, I don't know where exactly the `derby.jar` was installed on your system, but you have to mention the full path to `derby.jar` like `/usr/share/javadb/lib/derby.jar`. Then you can start your application by `java -cp /usr/share/javadb/lib/derby.jar:. TestDB database.properties`. If you cannot find the `derby.jar` on your system, you still can download it from the official [Apache Derby website](http://db.apache.org/derby/).

Comment: I find location of derby.jar - `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/db/lib/derby.jar` and with `java -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/db/lib/derby.jar:. TestDB database.properties` all work and print `Romeo`. Does I need to add derby to classpath (I didn't do this before)? What do you think?

Comment: With the `-classpath` option you already set the classpath for this Java process. You can set the environment variable `CLASSPATH` if you wish, but this is used for all your Java applications. Different applications may use different libraries, so most of the time it is better to set the classpath with the `-classpath` option. You can use a shell script to start your application without typing so much.